# AttributeError: module 'preprocessor' has no attribute 'clean'

Tags: python, attributeerror, preprocessor

I am trying to use the preprocessor library in order to clean text stored in a Pandas Data Frame. I've installed the last version (https://pypi.org/project/tweet-preprocessor/), but I receive this error message:

```
import preprocessor as p
#forming a separate feature for cleaned tweets
for i,v in enumerate(df['text']):
    df.loc[v,'text'] = p.clean(i)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-183-94e08e1aff33> in <module>
      1 #forming a separate feature for cleaned tweets
      2 for i,v in enumerate(df['text']):
----> 3     df.loc[v,'text'] = p.clean(i)

AttributeError: module 'preprocessor' has no attribute 'clean'
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a file called `preprocessor.py` in your directory or around?

Answer (score 5):

You probably have the `preprocessor` module installed as well, which is entirely distinct from the `tweet-preprocessor` module. However, confusingly, the `import preprocessor as p` statement can be used for both. When both modules are installed, Python ignores `tweet-preprocessor` and automatically opts for `preprocessor`, which does not contain a `clean` function, hence the error you received.

To resolve this, I had to uninstall both modules with the following commands:

```
pip uninstall preprocessor
pip uninstall tweet-preprocessor
```

Then I closed all shells for a fresh start and typed:

```
pip install tweet-preprocessor
```

And finally:

```
>>> import preprocessor as p
>>> p.clean('#this and that')
'and that'
```

Merely uninstalling `preprocessor` did not work. Python kept importing the module despite it being uninstalled. I am not sure why, but I suspect it has something to do with caches that Python keeps in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing first:

```
pip install tweet-preprocessor
```

Then:

```
import preprocessor as p
```